# Efficiently Boost voltage for small single burst of current

Tags: batteries, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, boost, low-power

How can I efficiently boost 4.2v ~ 3.0v from a battery up to 5v for a short burst of current? My load is essentially an RC circuit with 17.8R and 300uF that I need to charge as fast as possible to function properly which is roughly a 281mA peak that quickly tails off.

Comment: Switched RL comes to mind.

Comment: You could maybe explain why. Do you need an accurate 5V?

Comment: No just a voltage near 5v to 6v.I'm confused I have described the load as it operates now off a fixed PSU, the reason why is I need to run off a battery, and the chemistry of the battery only charges to a maximum of 4.2v.

Comment: What you're trying to do (with sllightly different numbers) is the classic "charge up a camera flash" problem. But instead of going from 3 volts to 400, you only want to get to 5. So basically you make an oscillator which drives a transformer with an output of 5 volts or so, put a rectifier on it, and charge the cap with that. If you want quicker charge, use a 6 volt plus transformer, sense the cap voltage, and stop charging at 5 volts.

Comment: What is the 17.8R? Capacitor ESR? Why the 281mA limit? Does it come form max battery current?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast that, or spend 50 ct on a step-up controller IC plus max 50ct on an inductor and a couple of resistors.

Comment: The 281mA is calculated from ohms law.

Comment: Charge pump IC?

Comment: There are buck boost LED driver chips for smartphones (high volume, low price) which should work well. Can't say more if you don't answer questions.

Comment: Do you have a MCU in your design already? Integrating a small software-controlled boost converter with a few external components wouldn't be too hard, and that would be very cheap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are charge pump ICs with offer regulated 5V output (2.7 to 5.5 input) with only one external cap and about your required output current. I cant provide you with part numbers because its against forum policy but one quick google search for charge pump ics is enough.

Edit: And effieciency is around 80% or even more at max output current

Comment: I don't think providing part numbers is against the site rules. I did it a lot of times. It is against the rules to *ask* for part numbers (shopping question), or to write an answer *only* to promote a specific product (spam). But providing part numbers as example of what can be used is fine, IMO. If in doubt, ask on [meta](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The load is \$C=300µF + R=17.8R\$ in series.

You need to charge this "as quickly and efficiently" as possible (these are conflicting requirements).

Let's try with a perfect current source of value \$ I \$ first. We want to charge the load to a voltage \$V=5V\$, this will take a time:

\$T = \frac{Charge in coulombs}{current} = \frac{CV}{I} \$

During constant current charging, the resistor dissipates power \$ P=RI^2 \$, so the energy lost is:

\$ Losses = PT = RI^2T = RI^2\frac{CV}{I} = RICV \$ (in Joules)

Once charged, the cap will contain an energy \$ E = CV^2/2\$ so efficiency is:

\$ \eta = \frac{ CV^2/2 }{ CV^2/2 + RICV } = \frac{ V }{ V + 2RI } \$

Let's plot the charging current and efficiency versus desired charging time:

[image]

As expected, the fastest charging has the lowest efficiency, as resistive losses increase with current. This is only taking into account the load resistance, not the losses in the charging circuit implementation.

A reasonable efficiency (80%) is achieved for a charging time of about 40ms.

You will have to explain what you mean by "charge as fast as possible". If you want 5 milliseconds, the solution could involve connecting the load to a large capacitor pre-charged to about 30 volts or more... or reducing the resistance of the load. If you want 100ms, then it will be a lot easier. To be continued.

Comment: The resistance of the load is fixed and unable to change.
Currently in my prototype it charges in approximately 30ms. That is a very good point about the efficiency that I was not thinking about, I believe 40ms should be fine.

What I meant by "charge as fast as possible" is that the load only functions properly when the current is high enough.

Comment: That's interesting information... due to the RC charging, the current decreases at the end, how does that work with the minimum current you talk about? or does it only apply at the beginning?

Comment: Yes, it only applies at the beginning. It only needs a very short, strong initial pulse. The rest of the current is unneeded.

Comment: So, do you actually need to charge it all the way to 5V? How accurate? Or just give it a pulse and don't care about the current?... In this case, would connect it directly to the battery at 3V work?

Comment: Yes it needs 5v due to the fixed resistance to deliver a strong enough burst of current. 3v does not deliver enough current.

Comment: OK, so you need 5V because you need the 281mA. What I meant was: once the load has taken the initial current pulse, if you don't need to actually finish charging the 300µF all the way to 5V you can waste less power.